# Scheme - truncate list

Tags: list, scheme

I am new to scheme. I am trying to truncate list in such a way that the new list should not contain first and last element.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, one possibility would be to use [`drop-right`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._drop-right%29%29) to remove the last element and [`rest`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._rest%29%29) (or `cdr`) for removing the first element:

```
(define lst '(1 2 3 4 5))
(rest (drop-right lst 1))
=> '(2 3 4)
```

If `drop-right` is unavailable in your interpreter, then just implement a procedure that returns a new list with all of the elements in the input list, except for the last one. You could even combine the removal of both elements in a single procedure. Here's the general idea of the solution, assuming that the list has at least two elements (otherwise an error will occur) - fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (truncate-first-last lst)
  (define (drop-last lst)          ; helper procedure for removing last element
    (if <???>                      ; if the rest of the list is empty
        <???>                      ; then return the empty list
        (cons <???>                ; else `cons` the first element
              (drop-last <???>)))) ; and advance the recursion
  (drop-last <???>))               ; call helper, remove first element from list
```

Don't forget to test it:

```
(truncate-first-last '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> '(2 3 4)
```

Comment: Instead of `rest` use `cdr` (as stated above). As for `drop-right`, as hinted in the last paragraph, implement a `drop-last` procedure, it's simple: just traverse the input list while creating a new list (using the template for this kind of operation, it's in the textbook), the only thing that's different is that the recursion ends when the `cdr` of the list is `null?`, not when the list is `null?` as is usually the case

Comment: Lopez - which textbook you are referring here

Comment: I assumed you're writing this procedure as part of a programming course. If it's not a textbook then the book, webpage, notes, or any other material you're using as reference. What I intend to say is: this is a pretty standard procedure, so the technique used to solve it must have been taught to you by some means

Comment: Thanks @Lopez for excellent guidance..with your advice I implemented it and it works :)

Comment: Excellent! just a couple of improvements: in a `cond` form, the last clause is `else` (the Scheme way), not `#t` (the Common Lisp way). And the `append` is unnecessary, the body of `trunc-fl` is simply `(drop-last (cdr lst))`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28186/discussion-between-neham-and-oscar-lopez)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way:

```
(define (compose f1 . fn)
  (cond ((null? fn) f1)
        (else (let ((fr (apply compose fn)))
                (lambda (x) (f1 (fr x)))))))


(define truncate-first-last (compose reverse cdr reverse cdr))

> (truncate-first-last '(1 2 3 4))
(2 3)
```